# Python poetry lock failed while building dockerfile

Tags: python, docker, python-poetry

This is my dockerfile -

```
FROM python:3.9-slim-bullseye
ARG CDP_DATAPLANE_USER_HOME=/usr/local/cdp-dataplane
COPY . ${CDP_DATAPLANE_USER_HOME}
WORKDIR ${CDP_DATAPLANE_USER_HOME}
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get -y install git
RUN pip install poetry
RUN poetry lock --no-update
RUN poetry export -f requirements.txt --output requirements.txt --without-hashes
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["python", "main.py" ]
```

However, when i run `docker build -t test-dataplane .`, it throws an error saying -

`ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c poetry lock --no-update" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1`

I'm new to docker. Any help will be really appreciated.

All I need is a way to use poetry with python3.9 inside docker.

Comment: Do you still have this problem? I tried to reproduce this problem but didn't get any error. You could try running `poetry lock -vvv --no-update` and see what it outputs